# Mirror screen from iOS to Ubuntu without WiFi support

Tags: ios

I have an Ubuntu device but I cannot use AirPlay since the device does not have WiFi support. I do have a cable but it seems useless in this case. I saw Zoom on macOS being able to grab iOS screen with a cable, but is there a way to do it on Ubuntu?